# C# library for converting geom field of SQLServer into set of google latlng

Tags: geometry, sql-server, google

Is there any C# library which can convert the geometry field into set of google latlngs? I have stored a shapefile into SQLserver table. From Sqlserver i want to read the geometry field data and want to convert this geom data into set of google latlngs in my C# application. Finally i want to save these google latlngs into another table in SQLServer.

Comment: was the input shapefile in wgs84 coordinate space?  I'm also assuming input shapefile was of point geometry type?  Also, was Geometry or Geography type specified in SqlServer table?

Comment: The shapefile is of type polygon and is in swreff99_1800 coordinate space. yes,Geometry type is specified in Sqlserver table. Can u guide me any suitable C# library for the conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about [SQL Server Spatial Tools](http://sqlspatialtools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Current%20Contents&referringTitle=Home)? You can incorporate it into SQL calls or use it in .NET code as well. The SqlProjection class might work for this. From the sample projection_example.sql in the source .zip:

```
-- Project point and linestring using Albers Equal Area projection
declare @albers Projection
set @albers = Projection::AlbersEqualArea(0, 0, 0, 60)

select @albers.Project('POINT (45 30)').ToString()
select @albers.Unproject(@albers.Project('LINESTRING (10 0, 10 10)')).ToString()
select @albers.ToString()
```

Also, look at [this post](http://sqlspatialtools.codeplex.com/discussions/81927) on the SQL Server Spatial Tools discussions site, here is some code from that post:

```
--CREATE A GEOGRAPHIC POINT IN WGS84 LONGITUDE, LATITUDE COORDINATES
DECLARE @point GEOGRAPHY;
SET @point = GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText('POINT(5 52)',4326);

--PROJECT THE GEOGRAPHIC POINT TO A UNIT SPHERE MERCATOR PROJECTION
DECLARE @point_mercator GEOMETRY;
DECLARE @mercator Projection;
SET @mercator = Projection::Mercator(0) -- Initialize projection (0 = Longitude of Central Meridian)
SET @point_mercator = @mercator.Project(@point) -- Perform the projection
SELECT @point_mercator.STAsText() UNIT_SPHERE_MERCATOR
--UNIT_SPHERE_MERCATOR
--POINT (0.087266462599716474 1.0661617106056684)

--SCALE THE PROJECTED COORDINATES FROM THE UNIT SPHERE TO THE WGS84 SPHERE
DECLARE @point_mercator_wgs84 GEOMETRY;
DECLARE @a FLOAT;
SET @a = 6378137 -- Spherical Mercator Radius in meters
SET @point_mercator_wgs84 = AffineTransform::Scale(@a, @a).Apply(@point_mercator) -- perform the scaling operation
SELECT @point_mercator_wgs84.STAsText() AS WGS84_MERCATOR
--WGS84_MERCATOR
--POINT (556597.45396636787 6800125.4543973068)
```

To get the new transformed points to another table, you can do that with a SQL call. Actually, you could probably do all of what you need to do in one stored procedure using the `SqlProjection` class.