# Transforming geometry coordinates from SRID 4326 to SRID 3011

Tags: geometry, sql-server, coordinate-system, srid

In SQLServer geometry field, I want to change the coordinates of geometry from one spatial reference system to another spatial reference system (from SRID [4326](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/) to SRID [3011](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3011/)) by using ST_Transform. But the destination SRID 3011 is not available in sys.spatial_reference_systems table.

How I do this conversion? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 7):

There is no native way to do this in SQL Server (isn't [ST_Transform](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Transform.html) a PostGIS method?). Look into something like [SQL Server Spatial Tools](http://sqlspatialtools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Current%20Contents&referringTitle=Home) and [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19676/c-library-for-converting-geom-field-of-sqlserver-into-set-of-google-latlng/19703#19703) from a few weeks back. Also, you won't find any projected coordinate systems in the `sys.spatial_reference_systems` table as that table is only GEOGCS and used for geography datatypes.

Comment: +1 I wonder if [this geocentric translation](http://georepository.com/transformation_1879/SWEREF99-to-WGS-84-1.html) could be performed in SQL?

Comment: ST_Transform is SQL-MM standard method.