# Change coordinate system using SQL or Javascript

Tags: javascript, coordinate-system, sql-server

Is there any built in function in SQL Server 2008 R2 which can transform the cordinates from 102100 to 4269 coordinate system something equivalent to `ST_Transform` from postgres.
If there is algorithm to transform coordinates then that can also help or the Javascript library then that could also help.

Comment: Please have a look at: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19917/transforming-geometry-coordinates-from-srid-4326-to-srid-3011

Comment: If you want to do this in JavaScript, you could look into[Proj4js](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj4js/)

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe conversion between 4326 to 4269 is not working using Proj4js.Is there any other library or algorithm ...??

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe I have converted geographic coordinates which is 4326 as input and I have tried converting to 4269 but the values did not change and even I tried 102100 coordinates that also did not change the value.So there is problem in conversion of any projection to 4269.

Comment: There will be a few meters shift between EPSG:4326 and EPSG:4269. How much difference were you expecting?

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe problem is that it will give me wrong count of number of asset and that can have major impact.

Comment: Please describe more precisely what steps you are following that result in no changes to the coordinates.

Comment: @whuber I have downloaded the application under the download page and selected 4326 projection and under that I have written the x and y coordinates and on the right hand side I have taken 4269 from the dropdown transform but that did not work.

Comment: What "application" are you referring to? What x and y coordinates did you try? What was the output?

Comment: @whuber I am referring Proj4js Javascript api to convert coordinates.I tried these -43.81347656248869,51.17934297927967 coordinates as x,y which is in 4326 and i got output same as input for 4269.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard spatial function within SQL Server to do this. You will need to use **[SQL Server Spatial Tools](http://sqlspatialtools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Current%20Contents&referringTitle=Home)** or if you are geodetically inclined, create your own function.

The **[proj4js](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj4js/)** JavaScript library can, one trick is to ensure your projections are defined. Also ensure you are including a version of the proj4js library that supports your projections, or you will need to do it manually by defining that projections parameters.

Here is some kind of psuedo code that should work:

```
var source = new Proj4js.Proj('EPSG:4326');
var destination = new Proj4js.Proj('EPSG:4629');

var point = new Proj4js.Point(-43.81347656248869,51.17934297927967);
Proj4js.transform(source, destination, point);
```