# Convert Latitude/Longitude to Lambert Conformal Conic in SQL

Tags: coordinate-system, sql, lambert-conformal-conic

How can I convert coordinates from Latitude/Longitude to Lambert Conic Conformal using SQL?

I've been working on project that will require me to convert between NZTM And LCC projections. It's related to [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214833/convert-nztm-to-latitude-longitude-in-sql-server).

LINZ don't provide a formula to convert directly between NZTM and LCC, but both can be converted to/from Lat/Long. I've been very fortunate in getting some help with the [NZTM conversion](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214833/convert-nztm-to-latitude-longitude-in-sql) and am now working on the LCC conversion.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't support coordinate system transformations. There are other questions and hacks outlined on this forum.

Comment: I'm a DBA. *When the only tool you've got is a hammer... everything looks like a nail* ;)

Comment: I hear ya... we use MS SQL Server, but maintain then ETL our data in PostGIS to MSSQL... works like a charm, but not sure if you have that need...

Comment: @DPSSpatial we run ArcGIS with ArcSDE on SQL. But we do everything in NZTM. I am working with NetCDF files based in LCC and need to translate points between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following SQL code is an implementation of the [projection conversion formulas](https://www.linz.govt.nz/data/geodetic-system/coordinate-conversion/projection-conversions) provided by LINZ.  I'm sharing here in the hope it may help someone else.

To convert from Lat/Long to LCC:

```
Begin 
Declare
-- constants
@GRS80 float = 6378137, 
@InverseFlattening float = 298.2572221,
@Firststandardparallel  float = -37.5 ,
@Secondstandardparallel float = -44.5 ,
@Originlatitude     float = -41.0 ,
@Originlongitude    float = 173.0 , 
@FalseNorthing      float = 7000000.0  ,
@FalseEasting       float = 3000000.0  ,

--input Latitude (Y), Longitude (X)
@Y      float = 41.72, 
@X      float = 172.48,
@a      float = 0, 
@f      float = 0,
@phi1   float = 0,
@phi2   float = 0,
@phi0   float = 0,
@lambda0 float = 0,
@N0     float = 0,
@E0     float = 0,
@phiIn  float = 0,
@lamdaIn float = 0,
@e      float = 0,
@m      float = 0,
@t      float = 0,
@m1     float = 0,
@m2     float = 0,
@t0     float = 0,
@t1     float = 0,
@t2     float = 0,
@n      float = 0,
@Fcap   float = 0,
@rho    float = 0,
@rho0   float = 0,
@gamma  float = 0,
@Nout   float = 0, 
@Eout   float = 0;    

set @a      = @GRS80 
set @f      = 1/@InverseFlattening        
set @phi1   = @Firststandardparallel * pi()/180
set @phi2   = @Secondstandardparallel * pi()/180
set @phi0   = @Originlatitude * pi()/180
set @lambda0 = @Originlongitude * pi()/180
set @N0     = @FalseNorthing
set @E0     = @FalseEasting
set @phiIn  = -@Y * pi()/180
set @lamdaIn = @X * pi()/180
set @e      = sqrt(2*@f-power(@f,2))                                
set @m      = cos(@phiIn)/sqrt(1-power((@e*SIN(@phiIn)),2))    
set @t      = tan(0.25*pi()-.5*@phiIn)*power((1+@e*sin(@phiIn)),.5*@e)/power((1-@e*sin(@phiIn)),0.5*@e)    
set @m1     = cos(@phi1)/sqrt(1-power(@e*SIN(@phi1),2))
set @m2     = cos(@phi2)/sqrt(1-power(@e*SIN(@phi2),2))
set @t0     = tan(pi()/4-@phi0/2)/power((1-@e*SIN(@phi0))/(1+@e*SIN(@phi0)),(@e/2))
set @t1     = tan(pi()/4-@phi1/2)/power((1-@e*SIN(@phi1))/(1+@e*SIN(@phi1)),(@e/2))
set @t2     = tan(pi()/4-@phi2/2)/power((1-@e*SIN(@phi2))/(1+@e*SIN(@phi2)),(@e/2))
set @n      = (LOG(@m1)-LOG(@m2))/(LOG(@t1)-LOG(@t2))
set @Fcap   = @m1/(@n*power(@t1,@n))
set @rho    = @a*@Fcap*power(@t,@n)
set @rho0   = @a*@Fcap*power(@t0,@n)
set @gamma  = @n*(@lamdaIn-@lambda0)
set @Nout   = @N0+@rho0-@rho*cos(@gamma)
set @Eout   = @E0+@rho*SIN(@gamma) ;

print N' @Nout  : ' + str( @Nout    ,10,8) 
print N' @Eout  : ' + str( @Eout    ,10,8) 

End
```

To Convert back:

```
Begin 
Declare
-- constants
@GRS80 float = 6378137, 
@InverseFlattening float = 298.2572221,
@Firststandardparallel  float = -37.5 ,
@Secondstandardparallel float = -44.5 ,
@Originlatitude     float = -41.0 ,
@Originlongitude    float = 173.0 , 
@FalseNorthing      float = 7000000.0  ,
@FalseEasting       float = 3000000.0  ,

--input Northing (Y), Easting (X)

@Nin    float = 6920054.29,        
@Ein    float = 2956806.82,

-- variables.

@a      float = 0, 
@f      float = 0,
@phi1   float = 0,
@phi2   float = 0,
@phi0   float = 0,
@lambda0 float = 0,
@N0     float = 0,
@E0     float = 0,
@lamdaIn float = 0,
@e      float = 0,
@m      float = 0,
@t      float = 0,
@m1     float = 0,
@m2     float = 0,
@t0     float = 0,
@t1     float = 0,
@t2     float = 0,
@n      float = 0,
@Fcap   float = 0,
@rho    float = 0,
@rho0   float = 0,
@gamma  float = 0, 
@Nprime float = 0, 
@Eprime float = 0,  
@rhoprime   float = 0,  
@tprime float = 0,  
@gammaprime float = 0,  
@phiout float = 0 ,
@phix   float = 0 ,
@LatOut float = 0 ,
@LongOut float = 0 

;   

SET     @a      = @GRS80  
SET     @f      = 1/@InverseFlattening        
SET     @phi1   = @Firststandardparallel * PI()/180
SET     @phi2   = @Secondstandardparallel * PI()/180
SET     @phi0   = @Originlatitude * PI()/180
SET     @lambda0 = @Originlongitude * PI()/180
SET     @N0     = @FalseNorthing
SET     @E0     = @FalseEasting
SET     @e      = sqrt(2*@f-power(@f,2))                                
SET     @m1     = COS(@phi1)/SQRT(1-power(@e*SIN(@phi1),2))
SET     @m2     = COS(@phi2)/SQRT(1-power(@e*SIN(@phi2),2))
SET     @t0     = TAN(PI()/4-@phi0/2)/power((1-@e*SIN(@phi0))/(1+@e*SIN(@phi0)),(@e/2))
SET     @t1     = TAN(PI()/4-@phi1/2)/power((1-@e*SIN(@phi1))/(1+@e*SIN(@phi1)),(@e/2))
SET     @t2     = TAN(PI()/4-@phi2/2)/power((1-@e*SIN(@phi2))/(1+@e*SIN(@phi2)),(@e/2))
SET     @n      = (LOG(@m1)-LOG(@m2))/(LOG(@t1)-LOG(@t2))
SET     @Fcap   = @m1/(@n*power(@t1,@n))
SET     @rho0   = @a*@Fcap*power(@t0,@n)
SET     @gamma  = @n*(@lamdaIn-@lambda0)    
SET     @Nprime     = @Nin-@N0 
SET     @Eprime     = @Ein-@E0
SET     @rhoprime   = SIGN(@n)*SQRT(power(@Eprime,2)+power((@rho0-@Nprime),2)) 
SET     @tprime     = power((@rhoprime/(@a*@Fcap)),(1/@n))
SET     @gammaprime = ATAN(@Eprime/(@rho0-@Nprime))
SET     @phiout     = PI()/2-2*ATAN(@tprime)        
SET     @phix = dbo.fn_phiLoop(@phiout, @tprime , @e)   
SET     @LatOut     =  @phix *180/PI()  
SET     @LongOut    = (@gammaprime/@n+@lambda0)*180/PI() ;

print N' @Latitude  : ' + STR( @LatOut ,10,8) 
print N' @Longitude : ' + STR( @LongOut ,10,8) 

End
```

The 2nd formula uses an iterative loop to achieve convergence.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_phiLoop](@phiIN float, @tprime float, @e float )

RETURNS  float
AS 
BEGIN 
DECLARE     
    @phiOUT float = 0,
    @cnt int =0;

WHILE (@cnt < 10) 

BEGIN

    SET @phiOUT = PI()/2-2*ATAN( @tprime*power(((1-@e*SIN(@phiIN))/((1+@e*SIN(@phiIN)))) , (@e/2)))
    SET @phiIN = @phiOUT    
    SET @cnt = @cnt + 1

END

RETURN @phiOUT ; 

END
GO
```