# Converting NZTM2000 projection to Lat-Long system using PHP

Tags: coordinate-system, php, transverse-mercator

Is there a way to convert coordinates from New Zealand Transverse Mercator to Google compatible longitude and latitude using PHP? I have tried PHP-COORD library, but it does not have the NZTM option.

Comment: NZTM2000 is EPSG:2193, Google Mercator is EPSG:3857. I know nothing about PHP but these codes might help.

Comment: It might be possible to use existing scripts for Transverse Mercator, such as [this one](https://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/10671.html) and modify your $LongOrigin (173°) and $falseEasting (1600000) to fit New Zealand Transverse Mercator.

Comment: @FSimardGIS I tried convertTMtoLL() and convertLLtoLCC() they throws division by zero error

Comment: Which line is problematic? By the way, LL to LCC is Lat/Lon to Lambert Conformal Conic, so you probably won't need that one.

Comment: @FSimardGIS I found another solution [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214833/convert-nztm-to-latitude-longitude-in-sql). Your comments were definitely helpful in setting me in the right direction